# How to prevent Ajax.BeginForm automatic submition

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, visual-studio-2010, razor

I am not submitting my ajax begin form. but when the razor page is loaded it is automatically submitted. I want to prevent this. I want to submit this when I will click the "submit" button.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index2", "Home", 
  new AjaxOptions
       {
           HttpMethod = "get",
           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
           UpdateTargetId = "retaurantlist2"
         }))
{ 
    <input type = "search" name = "searchItem2" placeholder="Enter Your Search Content">
   <input type = "search" name = "searchItem3" placeholder="Enter Your Search Content">
    <input / type = "submit" value = "Click To Search">

}
```

@Html.Partial("_Restaurant_views_for_ajax2", Model)

Comment: check any javascript on page, otherwise it is not possible to auto post form

Comment: Please give me an exam ple @EhsanSajjad